# Why typing.py differs in python3.7 between docker image and cpython source?

Tags: python, docker

I found strange behaviour between two python-3.7.2 versions. The first one I've compiled from [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/v3.7.2) on my host machine (Ubuntu 17.10) the other one is python docker image `docker pull python:3.7`

```
import abc
import typing


class Meta(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    pass


class Base(Meta):
    pass


class Type(Base):
    pass


T = typing.TypeVar('T', bound=Type)

class Variable(typing.Generic[T], Base):
    """
        Variable docstring...
    """

class Member(Variable[T]):
    __doc__ = Variable[T].__doc__


m = Member()

assert 'Variable docstring' in m.__class__.__doc__
```

This assertion differs between my host and docker machines. On docker docstring is inherited from `_GenericAlias` from `typing.py`.
In fact on my host machine where python was installed from sources `typing.py` does not contain `class _GenericAlias` but python from docker image it is under `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/typing.py:591:class _GenericAlias(_Final, _root=True)`

Why such behaviour exists? And how to prevent them in the future?

Comment: FWIW the assertion fails on my machine as well ("normal" installation of Python 3.7), and I do have `typing._GenericAlias` (Python 3.7.0 on Win 10)